# Unable to run json server

Tags: json, json-server

```
cd React/json-server
$ npm i json-server

+ json-server@0.16.1
added 229 packages from 124 contributors and audited 229 packages in 19.279s

$ json-server --watch db.json
bash: json-server: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you call it, you need to install it as a global command:

```
sudo npm i -g json-server
```

then try running it.

Comment: what does `not working` mean, what is the exact error?

Comment: When I execute the command in my answer I am then able to execute json-server. It is installed in: `/usr/local/bin/json-server -> ../lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/bin.js` . So I cannot replicate your error..